# TeXShop - How to hide commands like \index{...} to facilitate the readability of the source code?

Tags: texshop

I am currently adding numerous keywords with the command `\index{...}` to a book project. This makes the source code very difficult to read.

Is there any way to hide `\index{...}` commands in the TeXShop editor window?

To toggle between visible and invisible would facilitate the readability of the source code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. As far as I know, there is no such feature in TeXShop. You could write to the author to suggest it as a feature request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctl-Click (or Right-Click) on the Source Window Toolbar and `Customize Toolbar…`. Grab the `Colorindex` check box and drag it to the Toolbar and click done. From now on you can turn on ``index'' hiding by checking that box. It's not perfect: the index command and braces will still have the coloring of Commands and Marker as set under TeXShop-Preferences Themes Tab and the text in the braces will have the coloring of the Index setting. I use a Dark Mode that I've customized so that the \index text is a dark gray so it goes into the background.

Comment: I had no idea that this existed. I don't know how far it really goes to making the source more readable in practice. But maybe our eyes get used to ignoring the syntax colouring and looking just at the text, and hiding text inside the `\index` commands allows us to ignore it.

Comment: Dear Herb Schulz, your answer has largely solved my problem, thank you very much.